# How are String sorted?

Tags: java, sorting

Can someone please explain the output for following function:

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
    String str1 = new String("20");
    String str2 = new String("100");
    List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
    list.add(str1);
    list.add(str2);
    Collections.sort(list);  // list is [100,20] now
}
```

I hope that the sorting is working in ASCII values for the input, i.e. 49 for 1, 50 for 2 and so on.

Can someone please confirm?

Comment: Strings are sorted alphabetically

Comment: Since '1' is less than '2', no need to continue checking the other digits.

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#compareTo(java.lang.String)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

So [`Collections.sort()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort%28java.util.List%29) sorts Lists of [`Comparable`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html) objects, using the `compareTo()` method that every `Comparable` object has. For [`String`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html), [the docs describes this as](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#compareTo%28java.lang.String%29):

> Compares two strings lexicographically. The comparison is based on the Unicode value of
>   each character in the strings. The character sequence represented by this String object is
>   compared lexicographically to the character sequence represented by the argument string.

It then goes on to describe lexicographical ordering of two different Strings as being calculated using the following approach:

> If two strings are different, then either they have different characters at some index 
>   that is a valid index for both strings, or their lengths are different, or both. If they
>   have different characters at one or more index positions, let k be the smallest such
>   index; then the string whose character at position k has the smaller value, as determined
>   by using the < operator, lexicographically precedes the other string. In this case,
>   compareTo returns the difference of the two character values at position k in the two
>   string -- that is, the value:
>
> ```
>    this.charAt(k)-anotherString.charAt(k)
> ```
>
> If there is no index position at which they differ, then the shorter string
>   lexicographically precedes the longer string. In this case, compareTo returns the
>   difference of the lengths of the strings -- that is, the value:
>
> ```
>    this.length()-anotherString.length()
> ```

Answer (score 3):

Strings are sorted lexicographically, i.e. alphabetically, based on the int value of the chars that form them.

Answer (score 1):

When sorting a collection, the `compareTo()` method, defined in the [`Comparable`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html) interface is used. This means the order in which is sorted is specific to the type of class, in this case `java.lang.String`.

When you look at the API docs of the [`compareTo()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#compareTo%28java.lang.String%29) method from the `String` class, then you will see it says that:

> Compares two strings lexicographically. The comparison is based on the
>   Unicode value of each character in the strings. The character sequence
>   represented by this String object is compared lexicographically to the
>   character sequence represented by the argument string.

So in short terms, it sorted alphabetically, and since **1** comes before **2**, it will be first.

If you want to change that order, you can use the [`Collections.sort()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort%28java.util.List,%20java.util.Comparator%29) method and also provide a [`Comparator`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html) argument.

Answer (score 0):

it compares `1` to `2` at the first so what the result is  `2` is bigger so the act of sorting will finish at this time ,

think that you have this two number `110`,`112`

what the result is :

at first it compares `1` to `1` so they are equals , so it go to the next step

again `1` to `1` so go to the next step

here it compares `0` to `2` and here the act of sorting will finish